# Problem when switching off

Tags: mosfet-driver

I have the following schematic:

[image]
the switch (S) is not the right one but i hope it will do the purpose here.
It controls electro-screwdriver using 48V.
When I switch it off slowly, the voltage regulator blows (IC1).

Datasheet:
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXTR2112FQ.pdf

I added the diode (D2), it helps but not 100%.
Is there any solution for this problem without the need to change the schematic?

Would adding a resistor as voltage drop instead of 0ohm (R1) help and which value?

The +48V is the power supply
The 48V:
[image]
Taken after J3 (pin1) and befor R1

And the output of the regulator:
[image]
Taken after (IC1) pin2 after both C9 and C3.

The current consumption is 2mA.

The switching off moment:
[image]

Taken from the Gate of (Q1) pin4
The green line is the gate voltage (pin4)
The orange line is the source voltage (pins 1,2,3) to load.

The switching on moment:
[image]

Taken from the Gate of (Q1) pin4
The green Line is the gate voltage
The orange line is the source voltage (to load)
Both ocsillograms were taken and the e-screwdriver (load) were connected.

Comment: How much current is used on the 12 V? How about reverse voltage when 48 V disappears but 12 V is sill present?

Comment: `When I switch it off slowly` can you elaborate? What does "slow switch off" mean in your system? Is there also a fast/quick switch off?

Comment: According to the datasheet of the Mosfet-driver it draw only 225 micro A.
https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/609/ltc7004-3125761.pdf

The regulator can supply about 15mA.
I mean with slowly switching off slowly pressing the switch on/off bottun.
At that moment it flow a large amount of current and that make it blows, or so i think.

Comment: Slowly switching mechanical button = contact bounce. Please hook up your oscilloscope to input and output of the regulator and post oscillograms. Please measure your actual current consumption.

Comment: What switch? There is none in the diagram. What is `+48V`? How long wires?

Comment: @ Tim Williams:

this switch:
https://m2bswitches.eu/producto/rl-15y/.  +48V is the power supply

Comment: Capture the switching off moment.

Comment: @winny, i did it, the switching on and switching off moment.

Comment: Why is there a sawtooth between 9-14 V before you switch on?

Comment: This is because of boost diode D1 and capcacitor C1 i would say.

Comment: I don't understand. If the +48 V is switched off, the entire circuit is unpowered and all other voltages should be zero.

Comment: Yes but in this oszigram the 12V (output of regulator is present) and the Mosfet driver ist supplied but the suplly for the pin which in turn switchs the Mosfet is off. Of course when i switch both off then there is no voltage: 0V. In the previous comment i tried to explain why the gate voltage is sawtooth.

Comment: This is becoming close to being closed as _unclear_. Please draw and switch as a switch in your schematic. Draw all voltage sources, even external ones as voltage sources and name relevant nodes. Explain each oscillogram in what setup they were taken from, referring to node and component names. Explain each trace in each oscillogram.

Comment: @ winny  i drew the main voltage and the switch too in the schematic and i tried to explain all the ocsillograms.

Comment: Are you injecting both 48 and 12 V into your circuit?

Comment: @ winny No, i am injecting only 48V into the circuit.  The 12V is generated from injected 48V by the (IC1) regolator to supply the Mosfet-Driver (U1).

Comment: Then how is 12 V saw tooth available at the time of 48 V turn-on?

Comment: In ocsillogram is available because i injected the 12V just for test puprose, but now it is not available so when 48V is off there is no 12V too.